# How to read a file on Anaconda, using macOS?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda

I'm trying to open a .tnt format file on spyder(Anaconda) using the nmrglue module.

```
import nmrglue as ng
dic, data = ng.tecmag.read("~/Desktop/Spectra001.tnt")
```

I'm using the appropiate commands as stated in their manual (pg. 85) - https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/nmrglue/latest/nmrglue.pdf, but spyder can't read or even find the file. 
Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the library you are using is not expanding home dir `~`

Try

```
import os
dic, data = ng.tecmag.read(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Spectra001.tnt'))
```

`os.path.expanduser` expands `~` or `~myuser` to their respective home folders.